# Does it make sense to call a hyperbola a pair of hyperbolas?

Tags: geometry

Every definition of a hyperbola I could find describes it in the traditional way that we're all familiar with where it ends up looking like two detached curves, except one. When I type "define hyperbola" into Google, the Google definition is:

> a symmetrical open curve formed by the intersection of a circular cone
>   with a plane at a smaller angle with its axis than the side of the
>   cone.

At first this looked all right, but after I read the second definition I noticed that they didn't mean doubly infinite cone when they said cone. The second definition is:

> the pair of hyperbolas formed by the intersection of a plane with two
>   equal cones on opposites of the same vertex.

So this is suggesting that each half of what we'd normally consider a hyperbola is itself a hyperbola. They're saying a hyperbola is just one unbroken curve like a parabola.

Is there something I'm missing or is that definition wrong?

Comment: A connected component of a hyperbola is generally called "a branch of a hyperbola," I believe.

Comment: Do you mean a disconnected component?

Comment: I don't think that's a thing. A _connected component_ of a shape $A$ is a connected subset of $A$ with no connected proper supersets. (A proper superset of a shape $X$ is a set $Y$ such that $X$ is a subset of $Y$ and $X\ne Y$.)

Comment: That definition comes from topology. In topology, a shape is considered to be the set of points contained in it, hence the set-theoretic language.

Comment: Y is a proper subset of X if X is a subset of Y?

Comment: No. Y is a proper _superset_ of X if X is a proper subset of Y. ("Proper" just adds the condition that they're unequal.)

Comment: Oh, I must have read that wrong. I still don't know what you mean by connected, though.

Comment: Connected just means that it's not in pieces. A hyperbola is not connected, but its branches are. A connected component is basically a piece that's connected, but isn't part of a larger connected piece. So, half of a branch isn't a connected component of a hyperbola (though it's connected); the connected components of a hyperbola are its branches.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google precedes the second definition with the label "MATHEMATICS," which suggests it is about to be more technically precise.  (It's a little funky, though, for it to say, in effect, that *a* hyperbola is a *pair* of hyperbolas.)  It's probably not uncommon for people to say "hyperbola" when they actually mean "one branch of a hyperbola."

Answer (score 5):

In the traditional definition "cone" means "doubly infinite cone", i.e. the shape you get from all lines through a point and a circle.

Answer (score 4):

In the "standard" terminology, one hyperbola has two branches.